# Angular reactive forms async validator not triggering

Tags: angular, angularjs, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular 8 (reactive forms) and I'm trying to check for unique email addresses in an input form control using an async validator. I've successfully implemented the same async validation on a different in input in the same form. For some reason that I can't figure out, the async validator for the email isn't triggering or acting as it should.

The two fields currently using async validators are the code and email fields. The code field uses 3 built in validators (required, minLength, maxLength) and an async validator that calls a service that receives all the codes from a table and compares the code in the control to the each element in the returned results.

The email field uses 2 built in validators (required, email) and an async validator that compares what is in the email control to all the values returned from a service. What seems to be happening is that the async validation doesn't trigger the error message until there is an issue with the built in email validator. When the email format is made incorrect, then both errors appear (the email error and the unique error)

I've googled and read quite a few stack overflow posts, tried out the suggestions, but nothing has has worked. I wonder if there is a conflict with what the async function returns { 'email': true } and what the built in validator "Validator.email" returns. Additionally, I tried implementing the email control in multiple ways - as seen with the comment tags, and none of those returned any better result.

Any help greatly appreciated

[image]

Template code:

```
<mat-form-field 
   style="height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; width:230px" 
   floatPlaceholder="always" 
   hintLabel="User's Initials, max 3 characters">
        <input tabindex="3" matInput class="mfbds-inlineselect"
           required 
           type="text"
           name="code" 
           placeholder='Code (required)'
           formControlName="code"
           [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':(bioUserForm.get('code').touched && !bioUserForm.get('code').valid) }">
           <mat-error *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('code').touched && !bioUserForm.get('code').valid">
                  <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('code').errors?.required">
                        Please enter the code.
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('code').errors?.minlength">
                        The code must be at least 2 characters.
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('code').errors?.maxlength">
                        The code must be less than 3 characters.
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('code').errors?.code">
                        The code you entered is already in use. 
                        Please append a 1, 2, or 3... to your code and try again.
                  </span>
               </mat-error>
           </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field style="height:40px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; width:230px" 
                floatPlaceholder="always"
                hintLabel="Standard email format">
                    <input tabindex="4" matInput class="mfbds-inlineselect"
                    required
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    displayField='email' 
                    displayCode='email' 
                    idField="id" 
                    placeholder='Email (required)'
                    formControlName="email"
                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':(bioUserForm.get('email').touched && !bioUserForm.get('email').valid) }">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').touched && !bioUserForm.get('email').valid">
                        <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.required">
                            The email cannot be null or empty. Please enter a valid email.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.email">
                            The email you entered is not a valid email format.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.email">
                            The email you entered is already in use.
                        </span>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

component code for async validators:

```
uniqueCodeAsyncValidator(tableName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return this.lookupsService.getValues(tableName).then(
            values => {
                if(control.value !== null && (values.some(el => el.code.toLowerCase() === control.value.toLowerCase()))){
                    return { 'code' : true };
                }
                return null;
            },
            error => <any>error
        );
    }
}


uniqueEmailAsyncValidator(tableName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return this.lookupsService.getValues(tableName).then(
            values => {
                if(control.value !== null && (values.some(el => {
                    if(el.email === null){
                        return null;
                    } else if (el.email.toLowerCase().trim() === control.value.toLowerCase().trim()){
                        return { 'email' : true };
                    }
                })))   
                return null;       
            },
            error => <any>error
        );
    }
}
```

Component code for ngOnInit and save functions

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.bioUserForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName:['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        code: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(3)], this.uniqueCodeAsyncValidator("person")], //uniqueValidator checks a table to see if value not already in use
        // email: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email], this.uniqueEmailAsyncValidator("person")], //uniqueValidator checks a table to see if value not already in use
        email: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email], this.uniqueEmailAsyncValidator("person")], //uniqueValidator checks a table to see if value not already in use
        // email: ['',{Validators:[Validators.required, Validators.email], asyncValidators: this.uniqueEmailAsyncValidator("person"), updateOn: 'blur'}], //uniqueValidator checks a table to see if value not already in use
        agency:[''],
        startDate:['']
    });

save(){
    if(this.bioUserForm.valid){
        return this.lookupsService.postValue('person',this.bioUserForm.value).then(
            person => {
                let obj = {}
                obj['code']= "ORG"
                obj['name']= `ORG ${this.bioUserForm.get('firstName').value} ${this.bioUserForm.get('lastName').value}`
                obj['personId'] = person.id
                obj['agencyId'] = this.bioUserForm.get('agency').value
                obj['startDatetime'] = this.bioUserForm.get('startDate').value
                return this.lookupsService.postValue('personAgency',obj).then(
                    personAgency => {
                        this.bioUserForm.reset()
                        this.modalService.openConfirmModal(`${person.firstName} ${person.lastName} was added to the person table, ID:${person.id}, and person_agency table, ID:${personAgency.id}`,'').subscribe(res=>{})
                            return;
                    }   
                )   
            }
        )     
    }
    this.bioUserForm.reset()   
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to return let’s say `emailAlreadyInUse` instead of `email`?

Comment: I did. I followed Nikita's recommendations and it still isn't returning (displaying) the correct error message. It does however display the correct error message if the email format is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use the same condition (*ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.email") for both labels

[image]

Just change *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.**email**" to *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.**notUniqueEmail**" and return {notUniqueEmail: true} as result of the function

HTML

```html
<span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.email">
  The email you entered is not a valid email format.
</span>
<span *ngIf="bioUserForm.get('email').errors?.notUniqueEmail">
  The email you entered is already in use.
</span>
```

TS

```
 return { 'notUniqueEmail' : true };
```

here you can see a demo(Promise and Observable)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avynzr?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Still not returning the error message when the value in the control matches the value of the current element. Incorrect email format triggers. Checked the stackblitz example, it uses Observables. The service I'm using returns Promises. Wonder if the async part is causing issues. I tested using both of the following formats:

email: ['',{Validators:[Validators.required, Validators.email], asyncValidators: this.uniqueEmailAsyncValidator("person"), updateOn: 'blur'}]`. 

email: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email], this.uniqueEmailAsyncValidator("person")]. Other ideas?

Comment: I've added Promise demo as well. Can you share your code on StackBlitz?

Comment: I think your first recommendation should have worked. I'm going to take a short-cut as I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I think it might still have something to do with the async nature and the form and controls valid, pending, invalid settings. I will revisit the issue later. At this point I'm waiting for the user to submit and handling the error that is returned from the database. Thanks!